# RegEx to match words in comma delimited list

Tags: javascript, regex

How can you match text that appears between delimiters, but not match the delimiters themselves?

**Text**

```
DoNotFindMe('DoNotFindMe')
DoNotFindMe(FindMe)
DoNotFindMe(FindMe,FindMe)
DoNotFindMe(FindMe,FindMe,FindMe)
```

**Script**

```
text = text.replace(/[\(,]([a-zA-Z]*)[,\)]/g, function(item) {
    return "'" + item + "'";
});
```

**Expected Result**

```
DoNotFindMe('DoNotFindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe','FindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe','FindMe','FindMe')
```

https://regex101.com/r/tB1nE2/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple way to do it:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(?=,|\))
```

This looks for any word that is succeeded by either a comma or a close-parenthesis.

```js
var s = "DoNotFindMe('DoNotFindMe')\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe)\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe,FindMe)\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe,FindMe,FindMe)";

var r = s.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)(?=,|\))/g, "'$1'" );

alert(r);
```

Used the same test code as the other two answers; thanks!

Comment: Ah this takes advantage of the fact that , or ) will never occur before a (. Right?

Comment: Right on, so it won't match `DoNotFindMe(`. :)

Comment: And thanks for a good question...I had to dig up my RegEx knowledge that I haven't used in a while...took me a bit to arrive at this simple one haha.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var s = "DoNotFindMe('DoNotFindMe')\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe)\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe,FindMe)\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe,FindMe,FindMe)";
var r = s.replace(/(\([^)]+\))/g, function($0, $1) { 
       return $1.replace(/(\b[a-z]+(?=[,)]))/gi, "'$1'"); }, s);
DoNotFindMe('DoNotFindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe','FindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe','FindMe','FindMe')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that avoids the function argument. It's a bit wonky, but works. Basically, you explicitly match the left delimiter and include it in the replacement string via backreference so it won't get dropped, but then you have to use a positive look-ahead assertion for the right delimiter, because otherwise the match pointer would be moved ahead of the right delimiter for the next match, and so it then wouldn't be able to match that delimiter as the left delimiter of the following delimited word:

```
var s = "DoNotFindMe('DoNotFindMe')\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe)\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe,FindMe)\nDoNotFindMe(FindMe,FindMe,FindMe)";
var r = s.replace(/([,(])([a-zA-Z]*)(?=[,)])/g, "$1'$2'" );
alert(r);
```

results in

```
DoNotFindMe('DoNotFindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe','FindMe')
DoNotFindMe('FindMe','FindMe','FindMe')
```

(Thanks anubhava, I stole your code template, cause it was perfect for my testing! I gave you an upvote for it.)

Comment: Ah I didn't know how to do a 'positive look-ahead assertion'. Thanks!